# Dropdown filter in datatable

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, datatables

I am trying to implement a dropdown filter to the datatable. All of them working accept this. Here I have to pass multiple values for "value" attribute of the option.

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <% 
String vendor=null;
        String queryi = "SELECT ICODE FROM VENDOR_ITEM_DETAILS Where VCODE=" + vcd;
        Statement stmti = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rsi = stmti.executeQuery(queryi);

        try
        {
            while (rsi.next()) 
            { 
                vendor = rsi.getString("ICODE");

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            out.println(ex);
        }
    %>

    <option value="<%= vendor%>"><%= rsv.getString("VNAME")%></option>
```

I tried above. It's working fine. But Since each time  the variable will be over written it can store only last values(more than one). So as a solution I planned to use array as below but it's not working.

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <%
String[] Array1=null;
Array1 = new String[100];
String join1=null;
        String queryi = "SELECT ICODE FROM VENDOR_ITEM_DETAILS Where VCODE=" + vcd;
        Statement stmti = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rsi = stmti.executeQuery(queryi);

        try
        {
            while (rsi.next()) 

                Array1[i++] = rsi.getString("ICODE");


           join1 = String.join("|", Array1);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            out.println(ex);
        }

    %>

    <option value="<%= join1%>"><%= rsv.getString("VNAME")%></option>
```

Can anyone please let me know if there is any other solution?

Some how I made it substitute values. But the values are appears as here :

value="abc|dec|dfr|ffff"

now I am searching for the solution to include value saparated by | to be included in double quotes as below.

value="abc"|"dec"|"dfr"|"ffff"

Comment: why the double quotes? ive not work with datatable before but i think you can do it using `join1 = String.join('"|"', Array1);` this will output `value="abc"|"dec"|"dfr"|"ffff"` but this is invalid html attribute values

Comment: @MamdouhFreelance thanks for the replay. But the above throws syntax error

Comment: Yes, that what i said.

Comment: now join1=a|b|c|c . Do you have any idea how can I make it join1="a"|"b"|"c"|"c" ?

Comment: You can work with your code `.join("|",Array1)` then handle with jquery `$("select").val().split("|")` and this will return array `["abc","dec","dfr".....];`

Comment: That's invalid syntax also you never need to do that.

Comment: hmm. join1 is a variable already having a|b|c|c these values. Now i just need to include strings in double quotes. any built in with java of regex might help.

Comment: OK well, how you will handle this values jQuery side? you will convert it to array?

Comment: I will just subtitute it in <options> value part. Since I am using JSP, Server side variable can be accessed like below <option  value="<%= join1%>" >name</option> . So no worries. I just need to do the abov changes now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127590/discussion-between-mamdouh-freelance-and-safoora-safu).